# Determining the relations for dimensionless numbers by using their definition

Tags: notation, dimensional-analysis

I often see that dimensionless numbers are determined by using their definitions, by the method as shown in the figure:

[image: 1]

However, I'm having trouble with what is really happening? What does that symbol '~' stand for? Why did they take the length simply $L$, velocity $w$?

Is there something to do with order of magnitudes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fluid dynamics, exact numerical relationships and equalities are often too restrictive to be of broad utility.  Particularly when working with dimensional analysis, small numerical factors ($\pi,\sqrt{2},$ etc) aren't important when trying to understand how various quantities scale with one another.

Take for instance the "characteristic size" $\ell$. For a cube, it seems reasonable to take that to be the length of one side, but what about for a less regular shape like, say, an American football?

[image]

What do you choose here?  Do you choose the length, or the diameter through the center, or the average of the two?  The point is that it doesn't really matter - the characteristic size of the ball, which is somewhere in the neighborhood of 20 cm, is a rough estimate.  If it's flying through the air at 20 m/s, then the characteristic time $\tau \sim \ell/w \sim 0.01$ seconds.  This sets the time scale for an air parcel to flow around the ball.

The value of this number is not as a numerically accurate statement about reality but rather as a scaling factor. It gives us an order of magnitude estimate for characteristic phenomena, and it tells us how those orders of magnitude scale with the fundamental parameters of the model ($\ell$ and $w$ in this case).

So to answer your question, you should interpret $\sim$ basically like an $=$ sign, but with the added understanding that specific numerical values are not actually important, and that the corresponding relationships are understood in the sense of scaling and order of magnitude.

Comment: That was very helpful to me. I was getting an intuition it had something to do with order of magnitudes, but wasn't able to find anything which could confirm that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of the '~' symbol as meaning 'has dimensions the same as'.

Comment: This may help - [Shooting two projectiles at the same time with different mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646797/37364)