# Is there such a thing as viscous vapor?

Tags: aerodynamics, viscosity

I'd like to simulate a scenario where a character suddenly encounters very high air resistance due to volatile vapors that spread and stick around. Is it possible for some type of gas to be viscous in air as it slowly diffuses?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like a liquid, a gas can be viscous.

For objects the size of a person traveling at walking speed or higher, friction is not the dominant effect in air resistance. To move through air, you must move air out of the way. You must exert a force on the air to accelerate it. You must give it kinetic energy. Every force has an equal and opposite reaction. Air exerts a reaction force on you, slowing you down and causing you to lose kinetic energy. This is called an inertial force.

In most motion, either viscous force is much larger than inertial force, or the other way around. The ratio of inertial force to viscous force is called the Reynolds number.

Usually one of these forces is much bigger, and the other can be ignored.

Exact calculations are very difficult, but a rule of thumb is easy. And a rule of thumb is all you need when estimating which force is much much bigger than the other. See this post. [Shooting two projectiles at the same time with different mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646797/37364)

In general, for objects bigger than an insect, inertial forces dominate. Inertial forces are bigger when speeds get big - It takes more energy to push air out of the way faster. Likewise when cross sectional area gets big - More air must be pushed around.

So your character is more likely to slow down from the force of a headwind than a very viscous gas.

Comment: Okay, because this is contrary to what my professors had told me, to assume gas particles don't stick. Could you also possibly provide examples of viscous gases? Or, at least theoretical cases? This is not a concept I've seen. You're saying a cloud of gas could pull itself together with electrostatic forces or hydrogen bonds, and resemble an almost liquid state that slows travelers down through it compared to its surrounding terrestrial air?

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts. Hypothetically, let's say there was a very viscous gas that had a noticable effect of slowing down those who pass through it that was due to its viscosity and not drag forces. Is there a name for any known chemical with this property? I image it would diffuse slowly, but what type of chemical bonds could achieve this?

Comment: In general, a gas is much less viscous than a liquid. [Viscosity of Liquids and Gases](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/viscosity.html)